# JavaScript boolean value error

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my below JavaScript I get an error in the `if` condition called:

> Reference Error{value is not defined}

I don't understand why its not defined as you can see it already defined as `false`.

```
$("input:radio[name=aboriginal]").click(function() {
  var DifferentOccasionP = false;
  DifferentOccasionP = false;
  alert(DifferentOccasionP); // false 
  console.log(DifferentOccasionP); //false
  console.log(!!DifferentOccasionP); // false
  console.log(typeof DifferentOccasionP); // boolean
  if (DifferentOccasionP === false) {
    alert("ab" + value);
  } else {
    alert("ddddd");
  }
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Where you defined value?

Comment: alert("ab" + value) should be `alert("ab" + $(this).val())`

Comment: var DifferentOccasionP = false;
if (DifferentOccasionP === false){
          alert("abc" ); 
        }else{
            alert("ddddd"); // it's comes else part
        }
});

Comment: after updating the line that Ankit suggested ( alert("ab" + value) to alert("ab" + $(this).val() ) -- i ran the code and it works as expected.

Comment: Not problem with $(this).val() .

Comment: You edited out the problem with your question `alert("ab" + value)` - the `value` in this alert is what is throwing the `Reference Error`. You never defined what this `value` was. So it should be as @AnkitAgarwal said

Comment: if (DifferentOccasionP === false){
          alert("ab" + value);
        }else{
            alert("ddddd"); // comes this part
        }

Answer (score 2):

It is because you have defined `DifferentOccasionP`, but not `value`.
If you want the value of that particular input you have to get it like this:

```
var value = $(this).val();
```

Comment: Wasn't this already specified by me in comment. This still cannot be the answer as It was just an assumption in the place of `value`